# Grouping two Columns into single column with subheadings Column1 over Column 2

Tags: sqlite

I have a simple table like this:

```
COUNTRY SERVER
Germany R12345
Germany R23456
Germany BA1111
Germany BA1122
Germany BA2233
Germany BA3344
Germany BA4455
Belgium R98765
Belgium R87654
Belgium BA9999
Belgium BA9988
Belgium BA8877
Belgium BA7766
Belgium BA6655
```

I'd like to extract with an SQL statement to turn it into a single column like so:

```
ITEM
Germany
R12345
R23456
BA1111
BA1122
BA2233
BA3344
BA4455
Belgium
R98765
R87654
BA9999
BA9988
BA8877
BA7766
BA6655
```

To further complicate things

- I'm using SQLite
- Preferably, servers beginning with 'R' go at the top but this is a nice-to-have.

I appreciate this is an unusual request but it's this output that I need to produce!

Comment: Are you sure this needs to be done in SQL? It would be quite easy in application code, using a map/dictionary with the country name as key and a string list as value.

Comment: I hear you.  Not my choice but unfortunately yes.  In short, this is to be applied within a bespoke application's configuration and the only available conversion tool from one format to another :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get close with something like:

```
SELECT ITEM FROM
(SELECT country AS ITEM, MIN(rowid)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY country
UNION
SELECT server, rowid
FROM myTable
ORDER BY 2) A
```

Comment: I'd call that close enough!  Thank you itsLex.